# getting table contents with javascript

Tags: javascript

how to read data from a table  that haven't any id

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>td 1</td>
    <td>td 2</td>
    <td>td 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td 1</td>
    <td>td 2</td>
    <td>td 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td 1</td>
    <td>td 2</td>
    <td>td 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

i need the text inside td1 and td3 of all tr's

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask]

Comment: have you done anything or not show us some of ur work what have you done.

Comment: your right i tryed as below
x = document.getElementsByTagName("table")

Comment: but dont khow how to select TR & TD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This efficient code to do.

```
let result = document.querySelectorAll('tr td:nth-child(1), tr td:nth-child(3)');
console.log("result", result);
let len = result.length;
for(let index=0; index < len; index++) {
    if (index%2 == 0) {
        console.log("td 1 data ---", result[index].textContent);
    } else {
        console.log("td 3 data ----", result[index].textContent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach:

```js
//select trs
var rows = document.querySelector("table").rows

const trs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  const tds = [];
  // using rows[i].cells you'll get tds
  for(var j = 0; j < rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
     // using .innerHTML you'll get td's text
     tds.push(rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML)
  }
  trs.push(tds);
}

console.log(trs);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>td 1</td>
    <td>td 2</td>
    <td>td 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td 4</td>
    <td>td 5</td>
    <td>td 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td 7</td>
    <td>td 8</td>
    <td>td 9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Query the dom for the rows then loop through them and get the cell content from each row that you want

```js
const rows= document.querySelectorAll('table tr');

Array.from(rows).forEach(function(row){
  console.log([row.cells[0].textContent, row.cells[2].textContent].join(', ') )
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>td 1</td>
    <td>td 2</td>
    <td>td 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td 1</td>
    <td>td 2</td>
    <td>td 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td 1</td>
    <td>td 2</td>
    <td>td 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```